# Reusing Nav as dropdown menu on tablet/mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, css

I have created a nav which hides and displays the menu items and displays a menu icon when on tablet/mobile view.

How can this be adapted that when clicked on, the menu items drop down?

HTML:

```
<nav class="site-nav">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="index.html"><span class="icon-home"></span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu 1</a></li> 
    <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a></li> 
    <li><a href="#">Menu 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu 4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu 5</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<a class="navicon-button x">
  <div class="navicon"></div>
</a>
```

Here's my codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WbbRvK?editors=110

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: @AndreasNiedermair - thanks for clarifying, change made.

Comment: I don't understand the question: are you asking for a way to hide the menu and show it when a user clicks on your icon?

Comment: I would suggest that if you are doing an Angular JS application you use its inbuilt jqLite library. If you aren't then using jQuery. Which solution do you prefer, jQuery or Angular?

Comment: @No1_Melman - Angular would be the prefered choice.

Comment: @Sunyatasattva - correct, when then the screen/device is a tablet or mobile, the horizontal menu hides and transforms into a drop down.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend looking [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)

If you scroll to the bottom it shows how to do DOM manipulation with event handling as well.

My guess is that when the user clicked on the link you would change the CSS of the sub menu:

```
var location = {
     left: element[0].left,
     top: element[0].top
    };

var subMenu = angular.element('.subMenu');
subMenu.css({
     position: 'absolute',
     top: location.top + 50 + "px",
     left: location.left + "px",
     cursor: 'pointer'
    });
```

Obviously this isn't a complete solution, but thats for you to figure ;), hopefully I have pointed you in the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap makes this quite easy, provided that you are able/happy to add it to your project.

See the example navbar demo [here](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar/).

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, yes, Bootstrap is easy, i prefer writing myself.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it by a checkbox hack.

refer this tut: http://css-tricks.com/the-checkbox-hack/